# Why do multiple animations not play on my webpage?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate a sign up / log in page where if you click on the right side, the right div will move to the left and the left div will move to the right. same in reverse. I'm having trouble playing 2 animations at once, also I haven't really animated in css before.
Image of my site:
[image]

My Css:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
@keyframes example {
  100% {
    left: 0vw;
  }
}

@keyframes example2 {
  100% {
    right: 40vw;
  }
}

#right {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 40vw;
  background-color: #363e47;
  left: 60vw;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;

  animation: example 0.5s linear forwards;
}

#left {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 60vw;
  background-color: rgb(47, 52, 58);

  display: block;
  position: absolute;

  animation: example2 0.5s linear forwards;
}
```

My Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you cross checked if you are asking it to play for the number of times. Here is an example for you at https://tb1.in entry and exit of entry title.

Comment: I can't see any Javascript to deal with the clicking - or is that deliberately omitted?

Comment: I am just trying to get the animation to play, ill add the clicking part after